# PowerBI embed token capacity? Where to purchase it? who purchases it? user or application owner?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We have developed an application that can embed powerbi reports. We do not own the data and the users can belong to any organization. This should make it user owns data scenario. They go through Oauth2 flow which gives us ability to query their reports and generate embed tokens to embed their reports using their access token. Since our users were using pro account our application quickly hit the limit for generation of embed token.

Now my question is, in this case who purchases the Azure capacity? If we as the application owner purchase Azure capacity will we stop hitting the embed token generation limit? Or is it the user account holder and user data owner that needs to buy Azure capacity? I cannot find a good answer for this.

Comment: The organization in which tenant the report is published should buy dedicated capacity.

Comment: In our case, I'm guessing it's our users who have to purchase the capacity, because we only made the application which allows embedding of user reports in the application. We do not own the reports, and we have no management rights on the reports. The report is published in our user's organization by the user.